# Android - getResources().getIdentifier() not finding the resource

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I have an xml file which contains the following resources

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/t214" android:padding="3dip"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/t215" android:padding="3dip"></LinearLayout>
```

etc.

I have the following code:

```
String id = "t" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
Log.v("calendar", "id string: " + id);
// Get handle of LinearLayout
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(CalendarViewActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName()));
```

According to the log, the id string variable has the value 't214', and therefore getResources().getIdentifier() should return the int identifier so it can be used in findViewById, but ll is being returned as null.

Many thanks!

Comment: are u using setcontentview in your create function?

Comment: Yes, setContentView(R.layout.calendar_view_week);   and that is the layout that contains the views I want the handle for

Comment: Might the fact the LinearLayouts are nested be a problem? (They are nested within TableRow)

Comment: Having said that I checked R.java and all the LinearLayouts are there

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because 'this' refers to the subclass DatePickerDialog

Comment: When I changed part of the line to
getIdentifier("t214", "id", getPackageName())
it still returned null

Comment: I've discovered that the problem is caused by the ids having numbers in the id.

Is this not allowed?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether I understood the question ... however, the general pattern with findViewById() suggests code like this:

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.t214);